# Try catch unit test (jest) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have following script employeeJobTransferServiceLive.js:

```html
const createJobTrasferSetPayloadOutput = async (jobTransferSetPayload) => {
  const file = './output/jobTransferSetPayload.json';
  try {
    await fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(jobTransferSetPayload, null, 4), { overwrite: false });
    return JSON.stringify(jobTransferSetPayload);
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```

so I created following unit test employeeJobTransferServiceLive.test.js:

```html
const empJobTransferSrvc = require('../../../libs/employeeJobTransferSet/employeeJobTransferServiceLive');

jest.mock('fs', () => ({
  promises: {
    writeFile: jest.fn(),
  },
}));

describe('sendWFDRequest is called', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('Create and Write to the file', async () => {
    const result = await empJobTransferSrvc.createJobTrasferSetPayloadOutput(jobTransferSetPayload);
    expect(JSON.parse(result)[0]).toEqual(jobTransferSetPayload[0]);
    expect(result).not.toBeNull();
  });

});
```

The problem the compiler complain about test coverage for line return err; after catch.
I don't know how to create unit test to cover it.

Comment: You shouldn't _have_ the catch, turning the rejected promise into a resolved promise makes it harder to handle correctly from the caller.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what should be changed then?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is not best answer, but at least it works fine for me

```html
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const empJobTransferSrvc = require('../../../libs/employeeJobTransferSet/employeeJobTransferServiceLive');

jest.mock('fs', () => ({
  promises: {
    writeFile: jest.fn(),
  },
}));

describe('sendWFDRequest is called', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('Create and Write to the file', async () => {
    const result = await empJobTransferSrvc.createJobTrasferSetPayloadOutput(jobTransferSetPayload);
    expect(JSON.parse(result)[0]).toEqual(jobTransferSetPayload[0]);
    expect(result).not.toBeNull();
  });
it('should handle a writeFile error', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(fs, 'writeFile').mockRejectedValue(new Error('something went wrong'));
    try {
      await empJobTransferSrvc.createJobTrasferSetPayloadOutput(jobTransferSetPayload, logger);
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error.message).toEqual('Error: something went wrong');
    }
  });
  });
```

Comment: This is a bad way to write a test because if the method _doesn't_ throw an error no expectation is ever hit - you get a false negative, the test doesn't fail. Read https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous

Comment: @jonrsharpe So what is the best solution for my code?

Comment: You've already been told in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73546854/3001761, and it's in the linked docs too - use the rejects property.