# Jest - try catch unit test fails

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have problem with creating unit test using jest.

exportMyData.js

```js
const createJobTrasferSetArray = async () => {
  const data = exportData();
  const jobTransferSet = [];

  try {
    data.forEach((element) => {
      const JobPathArray = element.JobPath.split(/[,\r\n]+/)
        .filter((JobPathElement) => JobPathElement !== '');

      // Create an object
      const jobTransferSetObj = {
        coworkerID: element.CoworkerID,
        jobPath: JobPathArray,
      };
      jobTransferSet.push(jobTransferSetObj);
    });
    return jobTransferSet;
  } catch (e) {
   console.error(`Coldn't create jobTransferSet Array: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
return e;
  }
};
```

exportMyData.test.js

```js
const exportData = require('./exportMyData');

describe('Read data from Excel and creat formated json output', () => {
//Test passed through
  it('convert read data from Excel to an array', async () => {
    mockedJobTransferSetRaw.mockReturnValue(jobTrasfarSetRaw);
    const result = await exportData.createJobTrasferSetArray();
    expect(result[0].coworkerID).toEqual(jobTransferSetArray[0].coworkerID);
    expect(result[0].jobPath).toEqual(jobTransferSetArray[0].jobPath);
    expect(result).not.toBeNull();
  });
  //Test fails
  it('Error on convert to an array', async () => {
    try {
    const result = await exportData.createJobTrasferSetArray();
    result.mockRejectedValue(new Error('something went wrong'));
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error.message).toEqual('Error: something went wrong');
    }
  });
});
```

I know there is something wrong in my tst case, but I can't figure out the solution. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should avoid using try/catch inside unit tests whenever you can (just as a best practice). You can always use jest's helpers:

```js
    await expect(class.method(param)).rejects.toThrow();
    await expect(async () => class.method(param1, param2)).rejects.toThrow(Exception);
```

Second, your try is empty, how would it catch anything is nothing is being done?

So this:

```js
    try {
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error.message).toEqual('Error: something went wrong');
    }
```

Should become something like:

```js
    try {
    // call some methods, do something...

    } catch (error) {
      expect(error.message).toEqual('Error: something went wrong');
    }
```

And if you want to go further, you shouldn't even need the try/catch part, but I would start by fixing that empty try/catch.

If I'm correct, this is calling a method that will throw an exception

```js
    const result = await exportData.createJobTrasferSetArray();
    result.mockRejectedValue(new Error('something went wrong'));
```

I'm not entirely sure what you intended on doiung there, but it seems like you tried mocking your method's return after calling it? Maybe share some of it's logic so we can help you better.

Comment: I edited the code and now try block is not empty. for you suggestion to use jest helper, I am not sure how to use it in my case, I tried this: await expect(async () => exportData.createJobTrasferSetArray()).rejects.toThrow(new Error('something went wrong'));
But it fails and error said "Received promise resolved instead of rejected"

Comment: There's still some issues with your code, like:
`return e`
This is not possible, as `e` is inside the catch scope, and the return statement is not... Anyway, are you sure your function is throwing an exception? Because, it seems it is not... And you should not mock your function's return if that's what you're trying to test, it's useless to test a function if you mock it's return.

You're basically saying:
- HERE, PRETEND YOU THROW AN EXCEPTION
And after it does, you say:
- SEE? IT THROWS AN EXCEPTION AS IT SHOULD

Comment: sorry for the mess, now I cleased the extra return e. Anyway, I add try catch block just in case something wrong happened, what I am trying is to iterate through an array and crate a new object then add push it to new array. So the answer to your question, no I am not sure if the fuction is throwing an exception (unless something wrong happened) but in general what test case for mine snippt?

Comment: You should probably test what you know is going to happen. Unit tests are meant to assure a certain behaviour, so if you expect it to create a new object, maybe you should test that... What if your function receives a null param? Should it still create an object? Should it throw an error? (probably the latter)

Some people even say that, if you're having a hard time testing your code, it's probably because it smells bad and has issues, but that might be too extreme... You need to have in mind what you want your code to do in as many situations as possible, and that's what you're gonna test